# In app billing API v3 INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA is null in bundle when onActivityResult is called

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am implementing subscription billing using the Version 3 Billing API. After the payment dialog has closed (payment succeeded), control is returned back to my activity

Calling method

```
        String payload = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        bundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), mProduct, "subs", payload);

        int responseCode = bundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (responseCode == 0) {
             PendingIntent pendingIntent = bundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
             startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
        } else if (responseCode == 1) {
                mErrorMessage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.purchase_cancelled));
                mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (responseCode == 7) {
                mErrorMessage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.payment_twice));
                mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
                mErrorMessage.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.payment_general_error));
                mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

My activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Null
            String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA"
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the purchaseData string is null. This might be because I have already purchased this subscription ( a million times when testing ) - and that I should have checked with getPurchases() first.

Is it known for purchases to "go through - apparently with success", if the user tries to pay when he or she is 1) a current subscriber, or 2) in the period after cancelleation but before the service expires?

Comment: post your calling method

Comment: I have posted the calling method as well

Comment: i had same problem with android.test.purchased ....try to implement real product and test by using sandbox.... i think with android.test.purchased you always get null ..

Comment: I actually test with the APK deployed in Draft mode, and a real product using a test account I have registered. 

I think this may happen because I have already purchased the item, cancelled it, and are in the period where the product is active, but will expire on the next billing date. I will try with a "fresh" test Account and see if I get a non-null value on the first and actual purchase.

Comment: Regarding Sandbox; Test purchases are only supported for in-app products, not for in-app subscriptions. (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

Comment: I cant find this clearly stated in any developer docs; but when I call  getPurchases(), everything seems okay, the subscription was  purchased. 

The developer payload was from the first ever subscription. If I subscribe multiple times, the orders seems to go through in the user interface, but are not stored in Google Play. 

I  assume for now that the INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA item in the bundle returned in onActivityResult is null, and use getPurchases() to check if the subscription is okay in my onCreate() method.

Comment: @GlennBech did you resolve this problem? I have found today that the getBuyIntent, which had previously provided purchaseData upfront (before the transaction takes place), now yielding null purchaseData. Code which had expected the upfront data and had worked well for the last week+ is now failing. It's like the Sandbox started behaving differently o.0

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I found out that I was using `ITEM_TYPE_SUBS = "subs"` instead of  `ITEM_TYPE_INAPP = "inapp"`.

When I put the right parameter in, it worked as expected.

Comment: this doesnt address the question at all, OP specifies         
    String payload = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    bundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), mProduct, "subs", payload);

Comment: Nice catch. "inapp" saved me. Thanks @Repminister